# How exactly does openID works?

Tags: openid

I am learning flask and i came across this concept called OpenID. I am curious how they work.
It is basically a service provided by an entity A which has all our resources, then we just ask the entity B,C or D to contact entity A's server and they communicate , hence we dont have to do much of work in providing usernames and passwords? 
In short, is it

I might be terribly wrong. Do explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not flask related.

Btw you're right. An entity trusted by the final user keeps his data and you, in the middle, ask this entity for the users' data.
The entity normally asks user for confirmation and then sends you an OK or KO.

You can find everything on OpenID [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)

Successor of it are [oAuth and oAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) which are more granular (and complex) on resources.